# Black screen of unending errors in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, dual-boot, 20.04, freeze

I recently updated by system from 18.04 to 20.04. I am dual-booting it alongside Windows 10.

Today, while working as usual, my system suddenly froze. So, I waited sometime for it to go back to normal (i often experience random freezes), and suddenly this Black screen appeared.
[Black screen of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gieyS.jpg).

It has been more than an hour, since this error appeared and it is not going back to normal. I am attaching [here](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Lenovo-330S-15IKB-15-6-Laptop-Intel-Core-i3-4GB-Memory-128GB-Solid-State-Drive-Midnight-Blue-81F5018EUS-Notebook-PC-Computer/673970609) the specifications of my laptop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you powered off and rebooted? Does Windows still work?

Comment: The next time you are able to successfully boot, you could run `sudo journalctl -b` in terminal to see if you have any boot errors that relate to your graphics drivers or gpu.

Comment: I tried force shutdown by pressing power btn for 5sec, and after booting, both OS's seem to work fine. But, I still cant figure out the cause of that error.

Comment: I even tried `sudo journalctl -b`, and apparently there seems to be no issue related to gpu. As I already mentioned in the question, the black screen didn't appear after booting or something, it just suddenly appeared after a random system freeze, while I was working on my PC

Comment: After some low-level messing with the system, I discovered that the problem was with the SSD. I did recently upgraded my SSD and this problem seemed to happen only after that, this made my assertion more concrete. So, I again downgraded to the older SSD and its been more than a month with no errors so far.